# How to keep song playing between refreshes in browser in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, audio

So I have this right now to play audio on a page:

```
function startAudio(base) {
  var audio = new Audio()
  audio.volume = 0.7
  audio.autoplay = true
  audio.load()
  audio.addEventListener('load', function(){
    audio.play()
  }, true)
  audio.addEventListener('ended', function(){
    this.currentTime = 0
    this.play()
  }, false)
  audio.src = base + '/audio.wav'

  var player = document.querySelector('.player')
  if (player) {
    player.addEventListener('click', togglePlay)
  }

  var isPlaying = false

  audio.onplaying = function(){
    isPlaying = true;
  }

  audio.onpause = function(){
    isPlaying = false;
  }

  function togglePlay() {
    if (isPlaying) {
      audio.pause()
    } else {
      audio.play()
    }
  }
}
```

The question is, if they start playing the audio, and then click a link, they go to a new page. This page reloads the same index.js script. Is there any way for me to continue playing the audio where it left off without having to press play again? I get that you can store the offset in `localStorage` or something, but I don't know if there is a way to autoplay on page refresh or change of page. What do you recommend? I can't really make this a Single Page App (SPA) which would also solve the problem, but unfortunately outside the scope of the app.

Comment: Spotify web player doesn't have it even they have a react app. So, chances are slim that you can do what you want without localStorage. But, you can check serviceWorkers maybe? There might be a solution for this.

Answer (score 1):

Just as you said, use localStorage:

```
function startAudio(base, offset = 0) {
  var audio = new Audio()
  audio.volume = 0.7
  audio.currentTime = offset;
  audio.autoplay = true
  audio.load()

  audio.addEventListener('load', function(){
    audio.play()
  }, true);

  audio.addEventListener('ended', function(){
    this.currentTime = 0;
    this.play();
  }, false);

  // Reflect data to localStorage
  localStorage.setItem("audio", base);

  setInterval(() => {
    localStorage.setItem("audio_time", audio.currentTime);
  }, 100);

  audio.src = base + '/audio.wav'

 //...
}

if("audio" in localStorage) {
  startAudio(
    localStorage.getItem("audio"),
    +localStorage.getItem("audio_time");
  );
}
```

Comment: How do I do it so the back or forward button still makes it work.

Comment: This doesn't work :/ Browser hard refresh and it turns off.